# How to complete CLA on GitHub

Tags: github, contributor-agreements

I have submitted a pull request on GitHub and the organization asked me to sign the CLA before they can merge the pull request, who currently has the red label 'cla-required'.

How can I do this? There is a lot of information about the contributor licence agreement on the web but no one is concerned about how to complete CLA.

I found the link of the CLA on GitHub but there is no explanations about how to agree them: https://cla.github.com/agreement

The developer who asked me to complete CLA to can merge my pull request gave me the link of this tool: https://pandoc.org

Comment: Did you ask the maintainers of the project you want to contribute to what exactly they expect from you?

Comment: I understood what CLA is and why the organization asked me to agree this agreement but I don't find how to technically complete CLA ... Today my pull request has a label 'cla-required' and I don't know how sign CLA

Comment: Did you **ask** the **maintainers** of the project you want to contribute to what exactly they expect from you? Different organizations have different standards. It can range from writing "yeah I am OK with that" on IRC to sending in a hand-signed CLA by snail mail.

Comment: No I didn't ask, I thought there was a standard way to accept CLA. I found a procedure (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Contributor-License-Agreement) but system tells nothing. I'll ask what I have to do exactly. thank's

Comment: A CLA is an Agreement you're making with a specific party, so of course the particulars matter!

Comment: I'm somewhat saddened by the fact that this question received two down votes... I feel like we should be encouraging these sorts of open source questions around these parts... We can't expect everyone to be a lawyer or an expert at open source either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to ask the maintainers of the project you want to contribute to what exactly they expect from you.

Different organizations have different standards regarding what they consider a legally binding agreement to a CLA. It can range from writing "I am OK with that" on an IRC channel to printing out the CLA, hand-signing it and sending it by snail mail.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while for this answer, but I found myself in the same situation for jquery. If anybody is looking for that one specifically here is the link.

https://cla.js.foundation/jquery/

Answer (score 0):

For the Microsoft CLA, there is the link : https://cla2.dotnetfoundation.org/

It takes just a minute to complete (complete explanation here : https://adrientorris.github.io/github/how-to-sign-microsoft-cla-on-github.html)